# Socket.io - Emitted message is not received by other clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send a message through socket.io but cant see the message in other clients, below is my code. I can see the text when I log it in console on the keyup function but this message is never received by other clients

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');



editor.on('keyup', function(){
    var word = { id: 'room', user: 'user', value: editor.getValue()}
    io.sockets.emit('typedCode', word);
    console.log(word.value);
    return false;

});

socket.on('typedCode', function(word) {
    console.log('The server has a message for you: ' + word);
})
```

This is the error that I have received:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @Jer I have updated the post with the error that I receive

Comment: All i see is a socket emitter on the client and receiver on the server and you are not emitting back to the client and there is no client receiver, if you want the message to be seen over all other connected client you need to do a broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your whole code, but try it with the code below

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

editor.on('keyup', function(){
    var word = { id: 'room', user: 'user', value: editor.getValue()}
    socket.emit('typedCode', word);
    console.log(word.value);
    return false;

});

socket.on('typedCode', function(word) {
    console.log('The server has a message for you: ' + word);
})
```

Comment: Socket.emit does not work in my case. It also shows no error on the logs

Comment: Also, please note that Im doing this on the client side, if I emit from the server side it works just fine

Comment: I can't see the server side cod, i have a simple app is made on socket.io , it's available here https://github.com/Yassermorteza/Socket-chat , you can find the live version here on heroku https://socket-caht.herokuapp.com/ . i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

io.sockets is the default server namespace for all connections. io.sockets.emit() is used to emit from the server out to all connected clients.

On the client, to emit, you want to use your instantiated connection:

```
    socket.emit('typedCode', word);
```

Comment: This is what I had initially, it doesnt work and does not show any errors on the logs

Comment: socket.emit sends back to the server. You will need to handle that event on the server side and do something with it to send it back out to the clients again. This is probably why there is no errors. The socket.emit is correct, but your handler code is also on the client side, when it needs to be moved to the server.